# Calculations/conversions in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, math, formula, equation

I have a users weight and height and now wish to calculate their BMI.

The formula is: divide weight in kilograms by the height in metres (m) then divide the answer by the height again.

So the user weight is stored in kgs:

```
<%= @user.weights.last.weight %>
```

Whilst the user height is stored in cm:

```
<%= @user.height %>
```

So to print the BMI, any ideas where I would start. I just can't get my head around the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a method best done in the `User` model.

```
def get_bmi
  bmi = (self.weight/self.height)/self.height
end
```

Comment: So, should I include this is in Models/user.rb
`def get_bmi
  bmi = (self.weights.last.weight/self.height)/self.height
end`

How would I then print it in the view?

Comment: Why would a user have multiple weights?

Comment: But to answer your question, you would call this in the view with <%= @user.get_bmi %>

Comment: It is for a (very basic) weight loss app so the weight is always fluctuating.

Comment: Getting error:

'String can't be coerced into Float'